# Loop through ArrayList only selecting last element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I'm trying to have several images bounce around the screen, but only the last image in the `ArrayList` appears.

```
for(Letter l : Letters) {
    clearAndDraw(gameMenuGraphicsContext, gc -> 
        gc.drawImage(
            l.letterImage, 
            l.letterRectangle.getX(), 
            l.letterRectangle.getY()
        )
    );
    gameMenuGraphicsContext.drawImage(
        l.letterImage, 
        l.letterRectangle.getX(),
        l.letterRectangle.getY()
    );
    l.move();
}

private void clearAndDraw(GraphicsContext gc, Consumer<GraphicsContext> draw) {
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, gc.getCanvas().getWidth(), gc.getCanvas().getHeight());
    draw.accept(gc);
}
```

If I remove the `clearAndDraw` line of code, both rectangles appear but they smudge the screen.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Move this line:

```
gc.clearRect(0, 0, gc.getCanvas().getWidth(), gc.getCanvas().getHeight());
```

To before your `for` loop. Then it will clear the screen before drawing all rectangles.